# How to uninstall the WSL installation of Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10?

Tags: command-line

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft store. After hours of tutorials, I cannot get any further than a command prompt. No desktop, GUI, or whatever it is called.

My problem now is how to rid my pc of all Ubuntu/Linux files or whatever you may call them. Trouble is I cannot see a partition in disc management or anything about Ubuntu. Once again Lady Luck has vomited on my eiderdown.

Please help.

Comment: Why would you expect GUI in WSL? You can uninstall it like any other Windows application.

Comment: Simplified short translation of this question: How to uninstall the WSL installation of Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10?

Comment: `wsl --unregister <distroName>`

Comment: `wslconfig /u <distroName>`

Answer (score 31):

Uninstalling a distro via the settings or store didn't work for me. What did was:

1. Enter a cmd or PowerShell prompt,
2. `wsl -l` to see a list of installed distro names
3. `wsl --unregister <DistroName>`

Comment: I had to execute `wsl --setdefault Ubuntu-22.04` afterwards (otherwise, `docker-desktop` would have been the default WSL distribution)

Answer (score 27):

Uninstall a WSL installation of Ubuntu like a normal Windows 10 application. To uninstall Ubuntu, right-click the Ubuntu shortcut in your Start menu and click *Uninstall*.

To reinstall Ubuntu, download it from the Microsoft Store once again.

---

To (optionally) also uninstall Windows Subsystem for Linux:

Open the Control Panel and go to `Programs` -> *Turn Windows Features On or Off*. Uncheck the *Windows Subsystem for Linux* option there and click *OK*. Windows will uninstall Windows Subsystem for Linux, bash.exe, and lxrun.exe commands.

---

All that was good advice so far. The bad way to do it if nothing else works is to install an unlocker program in Windows 10, and unlock the file so that you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  karel. I am absolutely baffled by the situation I have with Ubuntu. I downloaded it from MS store, created a username and pword. After that I cannot configure anything past that point. I have looked hard at the files I downloaded by searching with Everything which is a great tool but now I have them I still can't delete them. I cannot see them in any uninstaller, I have two, plus windows delete apps. I don't think I actually installed it but the files are sitting there, somewhere, without purpose. Help to be rid of it all would be great.